# nodejs from 0.6.19 to 0.8.0: App crashes upon start

Tags: node.js

I'm developing an application (nodejs+mongodb+backbone) and my system runs archlinux.
Up until this morning I was on nodejs v 0.6.19-1 and my code ran peacefully.

Then i updated my system and nodejs v 0.8.0 got installed.

Soon after the update I got the following error while launching my app:

**node: /usr/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:62: void node::ObjectWrap::Wrap(v8::Handle): Assertion `handle->InternalFieldCount() > 0' failed.**

Tried to debug and saw that the error is thrown when loading a module.
This module has the following requirements:

```
var fs = require('fs')
    ,User = mongoose.model('User')
    ,Connection = require('tedious').Connection
    ,TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES
    ,Request = require('tedious').Request;
```

Unfortunately I'm not skilled enough to dig deeper (this is my first project with the whole stack and with javascript).

Now I can live rolling back to 0.6.19-1 but, I guess, sooner than later I'll be in need to update, so ...

Tried googling about that specific error but I couldn't came up with any hints on what to do.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This is obviously a node.js bug. Why won't you open an issue on their github page to let them know about this bug so that someone will fix it? https://github.com/joyent/node/issues

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will certainly follow your advice

Comment: As the pksunkara said, this also might be caused by some low-level modules used in your project, as node v0.8 does not guarantee binary backwards-compatibility. I overlooked this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error might be caused due to some stale compilations of modules.

```
cd app
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks pksunkara. Am trying this right now and, as of now, it fails requiring 'gzippo' module which requires nodejs < 0.7. Will try to remove that dependency and how it goes, before filing a bug report.